# Datatable shows list values number coming from API, select entries(10,25) not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, datatable, datatables

Show entries on per page is not working.
I fetched data for stock market from API request. my all data fetched successfully, but when i set data into jquery datatable, data insert successfully, but show entries on per page eg:- 10,25,100 is not working. entries paer page is set to by default same as it fetch from website, it is not changed. please help me to work it correctly.

index.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table class="table table-striped  stocklist">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>open</th>
        <th>High</th>
        <th>Low</th>
        <th>Close</th>
        <th>Volume</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>   
    
    <?php
    include('header.php');
    
    $queryString = http_build_query([ 
        'access_key' => '*********', 
        'symbols' => 'AAPL'
      ]);
    
      // API URL with query string 
    $apiURL = sprintf('%s?%s', 'http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod', $queryString); 
     
    // Initialize cURL 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
     
    // Set URL and other appropriate options 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiURL); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
     
    // Execute and get response from API 
    $api_response = curl_exec($ch); 
     
    // Close cURL 
    curl_close($ch);
    
    $api_result = json_decode($api_response, true); 
     
    // Output of the API data 
    // print_r($api_result);
    foreach ($api_result['data'] as $key=>$data)
    { 
      ?>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $data['symbol'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $data['date'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $data['open'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $data['high'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $data['low'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $data['close'] ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $data['volume'] ?></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
    
    <?php  }?>
    
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    
    
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.stocklist').DataTable({
          ordering: false,
          searching: false
        });
      });  
    </script>
```

header.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/dsr/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/dsr/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
     
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     
    
      <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js">  </script> -->
    
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to customize the drop-down which controls page length? If so, look at the [page length options](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html) example. If that doesn't answer your question, can you [edit] the question, to clarify the problem?

Comment: @andrewjames non i do not want to cusomizr the page length, my selected page length is not working. I edit my question. (Hope this is now understandable.)

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Not visible? Not showing any values? Not causing the page length to change? Something else? Can you clarify? What errors do you see in the browser's console (hit F12 to open)? Is everything else working OK apart from this one thing?

Comment: @andrewjames when i click on entries to change to 10 entries or 25 entries. datatable, not changed, datatable shows all the values that are coming from API.

Comment: What errors do you see in the browser's console (hit F12 to open)?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question, so that your clarifications are in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: @andrewjames there is no error in browser's console.

Comment: Try moving the `</body>` and `</html>` lines (near the end of your index file) to the very end. Make sure they come after the </script> tag.  In other words, make sure your script is inside the body of the page, at the end of the body.